Jacobian and Hessian of a vector
I am dealing with vector derivatives, and I am having a hard time generalising results.
What I mean is that I can compute the results by hand, variable per variable, but I would like to do it in a collected matrix form.
For example, consider that I want to compute the Jacobian $\textbf{J}$ of the function $\textbf{f}$, where:

$\textbf{f}=\frac{\textbf{v}}{v}$
$\textbf{v}=[x \ y \ z]^T$
$v=||\textbf{v}||$

What I did was computing the result of $\frac{d\textbf{f}_x}{d\textbf{v}}$, where $\textbf{f}_x = \frac{x}{v}$, and extend the result with logic to:
$\textbf{J} = \frac{1}{v^3}\left(v^2 \textbf{I}_{3\times 3} - \textbf{v} \textbf{v}^T  \right)$
I am sure my result is right, but please correct me if not.
I want to compute the Hessian $\textbf{H}$ of $\textbf{f}$, but I want to avoid repeating the process.
How would you show that the following relation holds:
$\textbf{J} = \frac{1}{v^3}\left(v^2 \textbf{I}_{3\times 3} - \textbf{v} \textbf{v}^T  \right)$
How would you extend this to compute the Hessian $\textbf{H}$?
Do you have any reference to matrix calculus that could help me understand the subject?
I appreciate any help you can provide.

As of the first part of your question, the Jacobian you have calculated is indeed correct.
As of the second part, I would like to note, first, that Hessian is typically defined for scalar-valued functions $$f: \mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$$
simply by taking all possible second partial derivatives:
$$
H(f) = \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1^2} && \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} && \dots && \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_m} \\
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_2 \partial x_1} && \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_2^2} && \dots && \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_2 \partial x_m} \\
&& && \dots \\
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_m \partial x_1} && \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_m \partial x_2} && \dots && \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_m \partial x_m}
\end{array}
\right]
$$
If you want to extend Hessian to vector-valued functions $$F: \mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^n,$$ you would have to arrive to what is called a tensor, rather than a matrix. Such a tensor could be thought of $n$ Hessians stacked together, each Hessian treating $i$-th component of $f$ as its input:
$$
\mathbb{H}[F] = \left[ H(f_1), H(f_2), \dots, H(f_n)\right]
$$
As it follows from the definition of $\mathbb{H}$ for vector-valued functions, it is of no particular use to have the Jacobian calculated, since Jacobian has all the components of $f$ in its rows, whereas Hessian treats scalar function throughout all its $m \times m$ elements.

Update:
Here is the answer to your questions in the comment section:
As of your first question, I think I'd change to spherical coordinates, calculate Hessian in those, and then change back to Cartesian ones.
As of your second question, I don't think it is a right statement. I suggest you use matrix notation and Einstein summation convention (i. e., summing over repeated indices) for $g_{i} = M_{ij}f_{j}$:
$$
\frac{\partial g_{i}}{\partial x_k} = M_{ij} \frac{\partial f_{j}}{\partial x_k}
$$
This quickly leads to $\mathbf{J}[g]=M\mathbf{J}[f]$.
Example:
Suppose we are given a map $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, a matrix $M$, and a map $g$, such that:
$$
f(x, y) = \left[ \begin{array}{c} x^2 + y^2 \\ x\end{array}\right], \\ 
M = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & -2\end{array} \right] \\
$$ and $$g(x, y) = Mf=\left[ \begin{array}{c} x^2+y^2+x\\ 2x^2+2y^2-2x \end{array} \right].$$
Then, the Jacobians: $$\mathbf{J}[f] = \left[\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_k}\right] =  \left[ \begin{array}{c} 2x & 2y \\ 1 & 0\end{array} \right]$$
and
$$
\mathbf{J}[g] = \left[\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_k}\right] =  \left[ \begin{array}{c} 2x+1 & 2y \\ 4x-2 & 4y\end{array} \right]
$$
Finally, if I were to take your equation, it would say:
$$
\mathbf{J}[g] = \mathbf{J}[f] M^T = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 2x & 2y \\ 1 & 0\end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & -2\end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 2x+2y & 4x-4y \\ 1 & 2\end{array} \right]
$$
which is not what we obtained earlier for $\mathbf{J}[g]$.
On the contrary, if I were to take my definition: $\mathbf{J}[g]=M\mathbf{J}[f]$, I would get:
$$
\mathbf{J}[g] = M \mathbf{J}[f] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & -2\end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c} 2x & 2y \\ 1 & 0\end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 2x+1 & 2y \\ 4x-2 & 4y\end{array} \right]
$$
which is exactly what we got by calculation in the first place.

Thanks for your reply.
Your comment made me realise how imprecise i ply i've put the question.
Let me rephrase then to:
How would you obtain the Hessian of the scalar function $x/v$, where $v=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, using matrix notation?

I have also noticed that if my function $\textbf{f}$ is pre-multiplied by a matrix $\textbf{M}$ who is independent from $\textbf{x}$, then:
$\frac{d\textbf{M}\textbf{f}}{d\textbf{x}}= \textbf{J}(\textbf{f}) \textbf{M}^T$
I would like to understand why this is the case.

Yes you are correct, i'm traspoing because of how the optimiser requires the input, but i was calculating the transpose Jacobian. Anyway I don't want to ask you too much in a single question, but how would you prceed to compute the Hessian instead? This is what I achieved so far, but I would prefer everything in vector/matrix notation.
$\textbf{H}(\frac{x}{v})=\frac{3x}{v^5} \textbf{v} \textbf{v}^T - \frac{1}{v^3}
\begin{bmatrix}
3x & y & z \
y & x & 0 \
z & 0 & x
\end{bmatrix}
$
I'm missing a way to express the explicit matrix in terms of $\textbf{v}$.

It's basically:
$
\begin{bmatrix}
3x & y & z \
y & x & 0 \
z & 0 & x
\end{bmatrix}
x\textbf{I}_{3\times3}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
x & 0 & 0 \
y & 0 & 0 \
z & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y & z \
0 & 0 & 0 \
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

Sorry, mate. I can't seem to see any other notation but using a custom vector $\mathbf{i}=\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \ 0 \ 0\end{array}\right]$ and the outer product:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 3x & y & z \ y & x & 0 \ z & 0 & x \end{bmatrix} = x\textbf{I}_{3\times3} + \mathbf{v}\mathbf{i}^T + \mathbf{i}\mathbf{v}^T
$$

Thanks for your time!
